# Unable to load data : out of stack space in Argocd UI

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, argocd

I have done following things:-

1. Setup the kubernetes cluster with one worker node and installed argocd from
   this link https://github.com/argoproj/argo-cd/blob/master/docs/getting_started.md.
2. Argocd cluster is running fine and I am able to login to argocd UI using username and password.
   Once I logged in into argocd UI , seeing error **Unable to load data : out of stack space** .

Could you please assist us.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem, but only using Microsoft Edge browser.  Using "incognito" mode with Google Chrome works for me.